# How to import Github projects into Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, github

Currently I would like to use this GitHub repository- https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture

How do I import this code into Netbeans or start a new project so that I don't get all of these dependency errors (i.e. log4j, google code, etc.). Basically, how do I get to the point where I can make the "Hello World" project on the page's readme (I don't need to know how to use it just rather how to import it). Also, would these steps be specific to just this project or should it work just fine for all GitHub repositories.

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the GitHub repository you're referencing is a Maven project, you'll need to open it as such within NetBeans.

Follow these instructions (with screenshots) [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices#Open_existing_project)

The key to this process is pointing NetBeans to the **pom.xml** file which existing in the root of the GitHub repo.  Then it'll download all the dependencies automatically.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine to get the project into Netbeans, but how do I create a new project that uses this source code (i.e. a HelloWorld project).

Comment: Build the project (which creates the jar files and installs it into your local maven repository), then create new maven project in NetBeans, where you add a dependency on the previously build artefact.